# Finding substring whilst ignoring HTML tags

Tags: php, regex

I need to match parts of string whilst ignoring HTML tags. Which means if user wants to look for string "foo and foo1" in source code.

```
Two strings, <u>foo</u> and foo1
```

He'd not get the match, because of the tags.

I've tried regex, but since the tags **can** and **don't have to be** there, it seems rather too complicated.

It's not server-side script. It'd be an application run from console.

**To be more specific:** it is for syntax highlight. So user wants "foo and foo1" to be italic, but part of it is already underline and wouldn't match anyway. That's why I can't strip the string.

Comment: What is the actual problem you have? Remove all tags so that users could match word combinations?

Comment: Perhaps a DOM parser, like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: @stribizhev Nope. Not removing anything from file and yet be able to find the string

Comment: @Croolman - Can't be done without making an intermediate string that has the tags stripped out. So that's your answer.

Comment: @sln Let's say I'd do it that way. 1) copy the input 2) strip 3) search for matches 3) do changes 4) concat those files - how would I do no. 4?

Comment: @Croolman - you might investigate how Google does it when you search, then select `cached`. Apparently there is a way. Probably use a dom to get content, then insert highlight, then reconstruct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the PHP function `strip_tags` to remove the HTML tags from the text.  Then do your search.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: This is the proper way!

Comment: I need to have them though.

Answer (score 2):

**Use `strip_tags` as you have been advised**, it is really the best way. However, if you want to have fun or experiment and benchmark your regex engine :) you can insert `(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?` after each symbol of the query passed, and you will have a match, and in the very beginning of the query (or the opening tag won't be captured).

Here is an example for a "foo and foo1":

`(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?f(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?o(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?o(?:<\/?[^>]+>)? (?:<\/?[^>]+>)?a(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?n(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?d(?:<\/?[^>]+>)? (?:<\/?[^>]+>)?f(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?o(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?o(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?1(?:<\/?[^>]+>)?`

This will match `<u>foo</u> and foo1`.

https://regex101.com/r/aF8fJ8/4

Comment: You would think `foo` and `and bar` would be atomic.

Comment: This is astonishing. Problem would be, if the search conditions are given by regex.

Comment: @Croolman: Then, you can implement it for a plain text search, and warn a user of regex option limitations. :)

Comment: Accepted the earlier answer as that is the right one, although yours elaborates more on the subject.

Comment: @Croolman  I thought *That's why I can't strip the string*  means you cannot rely on `strip_tags`. It is OK you figured a way out.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will ignore the <> and slashes in html tags, only extracting words.

```
(?!</?[^>]+>)([a-zA-Z]+)
```

just replace the [a-zA-Z]+ with what you want to match.

Comment: Do not use Regex to parse HTML.

Comment: This matches everything within < >