# JavaScript RegEx Ignore String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have search results returned from the server and a regex that highlights the result using words in the search query.

```
words = searchQuery.split(' ');

$.each(words, function() { 

  var word = this.trim();
  var regex = new RegExp('(' + word + ')(?!>|b>)', 'gi');

  searchResult = searchResult.replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>");

});
```

This works fine, until I search something like this:

Search term: "script with javascript"

Search result: "java**script** is a programming language..."

It should highlight the whole word like "**javascript** is a programming language...". However, since the string has changed from "javascript" to "java`<b>`script`</b>`", it no longer matches the second word in the search query. It also produces weird values when the value of `word` is "b", "/", "<" or ">".

My question is how I can ignore the `<b>` and `</b>` tags in the regex and match only the original search query? i tried using lookahead, but it didn't work.

Comment: Simply sort search terms by string length before highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think descending sorting the array by string length can solve this issue:

```
words = searchQuery.split(' ');

words.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});

$.each(words, function() { 

  var word = this.trim();
  var regex = new RegExp('(' + word + ')(?!>|b>)', 'gi');

  searchResult = searchResult.replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>");

});
```

Comment: hmm. this actually works. but is there any way to ignore the "<b>" and "</b>" in the regex? that would make things a lot easier

Comment: @ameernuri: Have a look at the similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28991840/3832970, though I do not know if you can modify a search query that much (e.g. if you allow a regex expression in it).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore anything inside a string by regex. Try to search whole words by use "\b"

```js
var searchQuery = 'script with lang javascript';
var searchResult = 'javascript is a programming language';
words = searchQuery.split(' ');

$.each(words, function() { 

  var word = this.trim();
    var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + word + ')\\b(?!>|b>)', 'gi');

  searchResult = searchResult.replace(regex, "<b>$1</b>");

});
console.log(searchResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but the word may not be a boundary. just like script in javascript!

Comment: @ameernuri give me an example with problem, plz